# Adding image in TableView Cell does not show

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I am adding image in tableVIew cell but it does not show. 
I am using if condition to give the image to button but it does not show.

Here is the code for the button addding

```
    addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    addButton.Frame=CGRectMake(590,2,42,42);

    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tab1Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    addButton.tag=indexPath.row;


    NSString*test=theData.Status;

    if ([test isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        test=@"Already Member of the group";



    }

    else {

        test=@"";



        NSLog(@"Else is also Working Fine");




        [addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    addButton.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:addButton];       

    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",theData.GroupTitle,test];

    return cell;
```

Comment: Have you got my point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add to cell's contentview. So do like this..

```
   [cell addSubview:addButton];
```

Comment: this is for ipad button not iphone

Answer (score 0):

your button frame `CGRectMake(590,2,42,42)` is the error

`frame.origin.x` is too big than screen size

it is only on size 320,480  in developing

640,960 is automatic

Answer (score 0):

// Create a table for different section of app

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (!cell) {

  ```
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  ```

  }

  /* IMPORTANT: As we are using a "Dynamic Type", when table view reload we must remove previous
   views from container.
   */

  if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
      for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
          [subview removeFromSuperview];
      }
  }

  // create a rectangle box for image view
  UIImageView *iconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
  iconImage.frame = CGRectMake(12,4,53.5,53.5);

  // Create a label for cells
  UILabel *cellName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,18,200,20)];
  cellName.font = [self fontForBodyTextStyle];

  NSString *cellNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.tableCellNames[indexPath.row]];

  // Select path row tab actions
  switch (indexPath.row) {
      case 0:

  ```
      cellName.text = cellNameStr;
      iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"condition.png"];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];

      break;

  case 1:
     cellName.text = cellNameStr;
      iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"videos.png"];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];
      break;

  case 2:
      cellName.text = cellNameStr;
      iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"provider.png"];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];
      break;

  case 3:
      cellName.text = cellNameStr;
      iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:iconImage];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:cellName];
      break;

  default:
      NSAssert(NO, @"Unhandled value in cellForRowAtIndexPath");
      break;
  ```

  }

  return cell;
  }
  Thanks VKJ,